# Haskell reexport linker errors

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I want to have a function in a `Foo.Internal` module that is used by other things in there, but it should also be exposed by the `Foo` module. When I reexport the function from `Foo` to use elsewhere I get linker errors. I am using stack to build the code, so it might be an issue there, or with cabal, not sure.

Minimal working example:

```
module Foo.Internal where
secrets = "stuff"

module Foo(secrets) where
import Foo.Internal (secrets)

module Main where
import Foo
main = putStrLn secrets
```

When I compile this with `stack build` I get

```
package-0.1.0.0: build
Preprocessing library package-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 2] Compiling Foo.Internal     ( src/Foo/Internal.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Foo/Internal.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Foo              ( src/Foo.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/Foo.o )
In-place registering package-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'package-exe' for package-0.1.0.0...
Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/package-exe/package-exe ...
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/package-exe/package-exe-tmp/Main.o:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `packazuEPdwTk5e5ZZOCOiVJMdOJ3P_FooziInternal_secrets_closure'
.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/package-exe/package-exe-tmp/Main.o: In function `S2Re_srt':
(.data+0x40): undefined reference to `packazuEPdwTk5e5ZZOCOiVJMdOJ3P_FooziInternal_secrets_closure'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `Foo.Internal` needs to appear in the `extra-modules:` list in your `.cabal` file.

Comment: Fixed the issue, thanks